# Android -how to make view fill only the rest of the screen only

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, view

I have a custom view which is intended to represent a coordinate system.
That view is used in one of my xml-files. 
Here's a bit from the xml-file:

```
...lots of diff views..
 <org.test.ScreenProximityView android:layout_below="@+id/screen_proximity_orix_edit"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/proxTest" 
          android:layout_marginTop="70dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
</org.test.ScreenProximityView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, I want my view to fill *the rest of the screen* only. When I use match_parent, I get a view that is as big as the screen, but like half gets clipped 'outside' the screen. 
So how do I resize my view so it fits the remainder of the screen Only?

EDIT: I am going to draw on its canvas like this:

```
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), 0, mPaint);
         canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, canvas.getHeight(), mPaint);
         canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mPaint);
         canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(), 0, mPaint);
         canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth()/2, 0, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight(), mPaint);
         canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.getHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2, mPaint);

}
```

Which makes most of the stuff stick otuside the viewable screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
android:layout_weight = "1"
```

for the view, which you want to occupy the remaining space. works with `LinearLayout` as parent view. and rest of the children shouldn't have any weights.

Comment: The parent view is RelativeLayout. What do I do then?

Comment: put the linearLayout as parent view, and rest of the views in relativeLayout , add this relative layout as first child to linear layout, and your view which needs rest of the space as second child to linearLayout.

Comment: alright, I've tried it but I still get parts of it outside the screen when I draw. I've updated my OP